# Opencart 301 Redirects

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, opencart

Having a problem with redirect in a `.htaccess` file on an Opencart store.

It seems that any URL with `/index.php?_route_=` isn't getting redirected.

For example, this works:

```
redirect /old-url-here http://example.com/new-url?
```

This doesn't:

```
redirect /index.php?_route_=some-url.asp http://example.com
```

Any idea or suggestions as to what might get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

You can't match against the query string using mod_alias' `Redirect` directive. You'll need to use mod_rewrite, and if you use mod_rewrite, you're probably going to want to stop using mod_alias altogether.

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} route=some-url\.asp
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://example.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

Another thing is - apart from Jon's answer - that URLs like `index.php?_route_=some-keyword` are used/created only internally and only in case you have the SEO turned on. In this case, you click on a link with URL like `http://yourstore.com/some-keyword` and this URL is rewritten into `index.php?_route_=some-keyword`.

Therefore you shouldn't be creating URLs like that on your own nor try to redirect from them. If you need to redirect, catch the first SEO URL to redirect it.

We do not know where did you put your changes into the `.htaccess` file, but if you take a close look at this rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

not only you'll find out it is the last rule there, but it also has this **`L`** switch which is telling Apache server that if this rule is matched, do a URL rewrite(, attach the query string [`QSA`] and) stop matching other rules [`L`] - this is the **Last** one.

If you need to redirect only a specific URL, do it the same way as redirect for *sitemap.xml* is done (for example) and place it **before** the last rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
# ...
# your new rule here - while the URL in the link is http://yourstore.com/some-url.asp
RewriteRule ^some-url.aspx$ index.php?route=some-folder/some-controller [L]
# ...
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```